# CCNet 1.5 with TFS 2010 - solution file never checked out from source control

Tags: .net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am new to CruiseControl.Net but have spent a couple of days setting up a CCNet 1.5 server and it is *almost* working but there is a problem which I am struggling to understand.

We use Team Foundation Server 2010 for source control so I have configured the ccnet.config file to connect to it.  Whenever I try to force a build It ends with the following error:

```
error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: app.sln
```

When I look at the working directory on the file system I can see that all of the files for the project have been grabbed from source control apart from the solution (.sln) file.  I have tried this with several different projects and get the same result each time.  I have tried searching the server for the app.sln file but it is not on the server, so for some reason it is not being grabbed from source control. All other files appear to be fine, including the project (.csproj) files.

If I checkout the solution on the same server using Visual Studio 2010 then it works fine and I get all of the files including the .sln file.  So it appears that something related to CCNet is filtering the sln files during the get source part of the build.

Here is an example of the XML from my ccnet.config file:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb = "urn:ccnet.config.builder">
    <project name = "projectone">
        <sourcecontrol type = "filtered">
            <sourceControlProvider type = "vsts" autoGetSource = "true" applyLabel = "true">
                <server>http://servername:8080/tfs/collectionname</server>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>password</password>
                <domain>DOMAIN</domain>
                <project>$/projectname/appname</project>
                <workingDirectory>C:\projects\appname</workingDirectory>
                <workspace>[SERVER_NAME]</workspace>
                <deleteWorkspace>false</deleteWorkspace>
            </sourceControlProvider>
            <exclusionFilters>
                <userFilter>
                    <names>
                        <name>admin</name>
                    </names>
                </userFilter>
            </exclusionFilters>
        </sourcecontrol>
        <tasks>
            <msbuild>
                <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
                <workingDirectory>C:\projects\appname</workingDirectory>
                <projectFile>app.sln</projectFile>
                <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
                <targets>Build</targets>
                <timeout>900</timeout>
                <logger>c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCNet.dll</logger>
            </msbuild>
        </tasks>
        <publishers>
            <xmllogger/>
            <statistics/>
            <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound = "true"/>
        </publishers>
    </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

TFS2010 and CCNet 1.5 are on the same server and for the time being are both using a domain admin account, so security shouldn't really be an issue here.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend upgrading to CCNet 1.6

There are several bugs mentioned in the release notes that fix the vsts source control block:

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/CCNet+1.6+Release+Notes

Comment: Thanks Rami A, I've upgraded to 1.6 but unfortunately it still has the same issue with sln files.

Comment: Enable logging in the log4net section in ccservice.exe.config if using the windows service.  Invoke a build and see the log file for any more detailed information.

Comment: You can also try setting deleteWorkspace to true to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I haven't been able to work on this for a few days but I will give these suggestions a try to see if it makes a difference.  Thank you.

Comment: I have tried these suggestions but have not had any more insight or success.  I have managed to get the build working by simply creating new sln files using VS2010 on the server.  CCNet is working now but it feels a like bit like I have hacked around the real problem.

Comment: I recommend comparing your new sln file with the old to see what changed.